# Combine multiple parameter expansion operations in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I've got a variable let's call it: `ENV` that can be set or not, and if set it's in lowercase. According to my `ENV` I would like to get some other variables (ex: `URL_DEV` or `URL_PROD`).

I know I can get my env in upper case with: `ENV=${ENV^^}` and set default value with `ENV=${ENV:-DEFAULT}` but is it possible to do it in one line ?

And generally, how can I combine bash operators on variables ?

I tried something like: `ENV=${ENV^^:-DEFAULT}` but does not work as expected.

My solution is:

```
ENV=${ENV:-dev}
ENV=${ENV^^}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot achieve nested parameter expansion in `bash` shell, though its possible in `zsh`, so `ENV=${ENV^^:-DEFAULT}` operation cannot be executed by default.

You could use a ternary operator in the form of `case` construct in `bash` shell as there is no built-in operator for it (`? :`)

```
case "$ENV" in
  "") ENV="default" ;;
  *)  ENV=${ENV^^} ;;
esac
```

But you shouldn't use upper case variable names for user defined shell variables. They are only meant for variables maintained by the system.

Answer (score 5):

Nested parameter expansion is not possible in `bash`, alternatively you can check if the variable is set using `[ ... ]` operator:

```
[ -z "$ENV" ] && echo "DEFAULT" || echo ${ENV^^}
```

Comment: `[[ -z ... ]]` is preferable to `[ -z ... ]` as it's build into bash

Comment: @Eric AFAIK `[ .. ]` is also a built-in

Comment: @CervEd I beg to differ, `[` is a builtin in other shells like zsh, but not in bash.  In bash, only `[[` is a builtin. To convince yourself, try typing `which [` in a bash prompt. It has been historically named `test` and both `test` and `[` are typically located under `/usr/bin/[`.

Comment: @Eric The way I read [the GNU manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-enable), `test` is a builtin. Seems [ubuntu says the same](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man7/bash-builtins.7.html)

Comment: @CervEd I don't see in your answer that you have enabled that builtin, so in your answer you're calling `/usr/bin/[` and you're not using the builtin. It can be a builtin indeed, bu only if you enable it. My point is that by default it's not enabled... and so it's better to use `[[` which is **always** a builtin.

Comment: @Eric `[` and `test` are builtins. Pretty sure they are enabled by default reading the manual. They are on my system. But if you're not sure you check `enable -p | grep 'test\|\['`

Comment: @CervEd I've tested with a script that calls in a loop `[` (60ms for 10,000 iterations) and `/usr/bin/[` (9 seconds) and yeah you're right, the builtin version of `[` is indeed used. I always believed what `which` indicated but I've been fooled by it. Sorry for the hassle, glad you insisted.

Comment: @Eric that's awesome! Always good with some empiric evidence  It's interesting that `which` points to `/usr/bin/[` and I'm not sure the nooks and crannies of it and how it interacts with `builtins`. In the end, there are ofc other reasons why one may prefer `[[`

Comment: @Eric and @CervEd, in the future use `type` instead of `which`. `type` is built into the shell and knows the difference between builtins, aliases, functions, and external commands. `which` is an external program and can only find other programs in `PATH`. Running `type [` in bash will print `[ is a shell builtin`. See `help type` for more details.